# How to fix SQLState: 42809 when calling a procedure of postgres db from spring boot application

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, stored-procedures

I am calling a procedure from my spring boot application, the database is Postgres 11. 
It's now returning SQLState: 42809. Could anyone help me find the cause? 
Code of my application:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Integer commentCount = session.doReturningWork(
                connection -> {
                    try (CallableStatement function = connection
                            .prepareCall(
                                    "{ ? = CALL sp_profile_creation_default(?,?,?) }" )) {
                        function.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER );
                        function.setInt( 2, dbUser.getId().intValue());
                        function.setInt( 3, dbUser.getId().intValue());
                        function.setString( 4, dbUser.getNameNick());
                        function.execute();
                        return function.getInt( 1 );
                    }
                } );
```

The error log output is:

```
2020-04-08 15:34:01.045  WARN 32324 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42809
2020-04-08 15:34:01.046 ERROR 32324 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : ERROR: sp_profile_creation_default(integer, integer, character varying) is a procedure
  Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.
  Position: 15
2020-04-08 15:34:01.051 ERROR 32324 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] c.c.a.a.v.e.RestEndpointExceptionHandler : error executing work
```

The procedure is working file, I tried to execute it in postgres command:

```
call public.sp_profile_creation_default(123, 0, 'sontest12112',0);
```

and it executed as expected.

The procedure definition script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE public.sp_profile_creation_default(
  IN        p_user_id           INT,
  IN    p_parent_event_id   INT,
  IN    p_name_nick         core.profile.name%TYPE,
  INOUT p_default_profile_id INT
)
...
```

Comment: Try `prepareCall("call sp_profile_creation_default(?,?,?,?)");`  (as shown [in the manual](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html#call-procedure-example))

Comment: I updated the question, please note that my procedure return a result. So based the instruction (CallableStatement func = conn.prepareCall("{? = call refcursorfunc() }");
I think my code was correct.

Comment: You have an out parameter not a "result". You have to use the syntax [as shown in the manual](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html#call-procedure-example) which makes your out parameter to be at index 4, not 1

Comment: So how I get out parameter if using call sp_profile_creation_default(?,?,?,?). In the manual, it doesn't get the out param.

Comment: The same way, but using the correct index: `function.getInt(4)`.

Comment: You are correct! Thank you. 
However we need to registerOutParameter too. 
function.registerOutParameter(4, Types.Integer);
function.execute();
return function.getInt( 4 );